# Wildfly cluster and Apache2

Tags: apache, wildfly-8, mod-cluster

I browse a lot, I see this question is similar to other already posted but solutions seem not working in my case. I built a Wildfly.8.2.0.Final cluster and I want to put it behind httpd, cluster is running correctly. On my host I run three Debian Wheezy guests, two of them run a cluster's node (IP are `192.168.0.101` and `192.168.0.102`) the other guest run Apache2.2.22 with mod_cluster.1.2.0.Final module. This is my mod_cluster.conf:

```
<IfModlue mod_manager.so>
  Listen 192.168.0.104:6666
  ManagerBalancerName wfycluster
  <VirtualHost 192.168.0.104:6666>
    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    ServerAdvertise On 192.168.0.104:6666
    EnableMCPMReceive
    <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 192.168.0
    </Location>
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Modules are loaded correctly and I can see the mod_cluster's manager page on `192.168.0.104:6666/mod_cluster_manager` but with no nodes info. I also configured a VirtualHost:

```
Listen 192.168.0.104:6666
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.104:6666>
  ServerName wfycluster
  ProxyPass / balancer://wfycluster
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://wfycluster
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 192.168.0
  </Location>
  SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
  ManagerBalancerName wfycluster
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/wfycluster/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Wildfly istances are run by using the default standalone-ha.xml. This is the command:

```
./standalone.sh -b 192.168.0.101 -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=srv1 -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.bind.address.unsecure=192.168.0.101 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.0.101
```

command refers to first guest. As nodes rises up there is no change in the Apache2 mod_cluster_manager page, and, if I look for `192.168.0.104/MyClusteredApp/` I get a `404` error. If I use curl directly on nodes everything works as expected. What's wrong in my configuration?

**UPDATE:** I add this line `ServerAdvertise On 192.168.0.104` and changed a line in this way `ManagerBalanceName other-server-group` in my virtual host file. Now I can see nodes and apache2 try to communicate but with no success. On apache2 virtual host's error.log I see this:

```
...[error] proxy: CLUSTER: (balancer://wfycluster). All workers are in error state
```

**UPDATE:** I change `ManagerBalanceName other-server-group` in `ManagerBalanceName wfycluster`, and commented lines `ProxyPass ..`, `ProxyPassReverse..`, and `ProxyPreserveHost..` about my virtualhost configuration. I also changed my Wildfly nodes configuration adding attribute `balancer=wfycluster` to `mod-cluster-config` tag in `modcluster` subsystem. Error changed in

```
...(UndertowEventHandlerAdapter - 1) MODECLUSTER000042: Error null sending INFO command to debian1-2.local/192.168.0.104:6666, configuration will be reset: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was messing with Apache2 virtualhost configurations. I change my `mod_cluster.conf` this way:

```
<IfModule manager_module>
    Listen 192.168.0.104:6666
    ManagerBalancerName wfycluster  
    <VirtualHost 192.168.0.104:6666>
        AllowDisplay On
        KeepAliveTimeout 300
        MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
        AdvertiseFrequency 5
        ServerAdvertise On 192.168.0.104:6666
        AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
        EnableMCPMReceive
        <Location />
            Order allow,deny
#           Deny from all
            Allow from 192.168.0.
        </Location>
        <Location /wfycluster>
            SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from 192.168.0
        </Location>     
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and change the other one virtualhost as simple as possible:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wfycluster
    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 192.168.0.
    </Location>
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/wfycluster/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Wildfly attribute `balancer` value and mod_cluster virtualhost `ManagerBalancerName` now matches. I can finally see nodes on mod_cluster-manager page. Maybe not the best conf possible, I have to dig deeper, but it works. Thanks @Bruno for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried without the ProxyPass directives? I am not certain you need those.

This is the basic proof of concept config I have used successfully:

```
<VirtualHost [HOST]:[PORT]>
    AllowDisplay On
    EnableMCPMReceive
    #allow access from cluster nodes to the mod_cluster module
    <Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from [SUBNET/VPN/... where the nodes are]
    </Directory>

    KeepAliveTimeout 60
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    ServerAdvertise On http://[HOST]:[PORT] 

    # This directive allows you to view mod_cluster status at URL http://[HOST]:[PORT]/mod-cluster-manager
    <Location /mod-cluster-manager>
        SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from [SUBNET/VPN/... from which you want to access mod-cluster manager page]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I commented the lines `ProxyPass..`, `ProxyPassReserve..` and `ProxyPreserveHost..`. The error has changed in `...(UndertowEventHandlerAdapter - 1) MODECLUSTER000042: Error null sending INFO command to debian1-2.local/192.168.0.104:6666, configuration will be reset: null`.

Comment: Do you have both of these VirtualHost entries in your apache config? Can you explain what the goal of the 2nd one is?

Comment: Also, have you completed/verified the config on the wildfly side?

Comment: I added `balancer=wfycluster` to `mod-cluster-config` in `modcluster` subsystem on every Wildfly node configuration but I'm still getting the same error. I updated my post. Two entries? Mmm I surely misundestand configuration..